# Angular: Access an element from Component using style class

Tags: angular

Is there a way to access an html field from the ts file using it's style class ?
What I'm trying to do is to show/hide few fields based on a button click. The fields are generated dynamically and I only have access to the style class. 
[Here is the stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-af7fwd) for what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to show/hide all fields with class="label" upon clicking toggle. mat-list-items are generated dynamically and I can't modify them. How best can I do it ?

```
<mat-nav-list style="padding-top:0px !important;">
  <a mat-list-item (click)="toggle(showText); showText = !showText">
    <i id="right" *ngIf=!showText class="material-icons" aria-label="Show icon only">chevron_right</i>
    <i id="left" *ngIf=showText class="material-icons" aria-label="Show icon and text">chevron_left</i>
  </a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="dashboard" class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>&nbsp;<span class="label">Dashboard</span></a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="order" class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i>&nbsp;<span class="label">Create Order</span></a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="order-search" class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <i class="material-icons">search</i>&nbsp;<span class="label">Order Search</span></a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="job-search" class="menu-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <i class="material-icons">search</i>&nbsp;<span class="label">Job Search</span></a>

</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "mat-list-items are generated dynamically"?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I'm using the below plugin for submenu. Please check the HTML section in usage. That's how the menu items will be created. The menu labels will have class 'label'. My requirement is to hide the labels on click on a button and display the icons alone. https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu

Comment: you forgot the quotes in *ngIf, you must use  *ngIf= **"** !showText **"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the HTML elements that have the "label" class with `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName`, and set the `hidden` property to toggle their visibility:

```
showText = true;

constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

toggle() {
  this.showText = !this.showText;
  const elements = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".label");
  const htmlElements = Array.from(elements).map(x => x as HTMLElement);
  htmlElements.forEach(label => label.hidden = !this.showText);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqdgzg) for a demo. Please note that the `(click)` event handler only calls `toggle()`.

Answer (score -1):

Better create a variable and use `*ngIf` condition on dom elements.